Problems using Apache `httpclient` lib to make 1000s of connections to localhost
I am trying to write a test case for a web server that's accepting POST requests with a small JSON body.
I am trying to simulate many hundreds of requests per second.  I'm using PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager to attempt to minimise the workload on the test program itself, since I'm interested in seeing how the server is responding to this kind of load.  I am running the test on the same machine as the server, so connecting to http://localhost:8080/example.
The actual test program is fairly lengthy since it's concerned with generating plausible data but the core bit I'm having trouble with is this:
    //
    // http connection pool is set up like this:
    //
    httpPool = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    httpPool.setMaxTotal(100);
    httpPool.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(100);

    //
    // then this is called frequently:
    //
    private void post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
        exec.submit(() -> {
            try  {
                CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(httpPool).build();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                post.setEntity(entity);

                try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(post)) {
                    //log(url + ": " + EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

Currently it's running just fine at about 150requests/s.  After about a minute it dies and every request throws this exception:
org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to http://localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: getsockopt
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:592)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5@5.1/org.apache.hc.client5.http.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory$1.run(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:87)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5@5.1/org.apache.hc.client5.http.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5@5.1/org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5@5.1/org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:407)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5@5.1/org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:168)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5@5.1/org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:178)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5@5.1/org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:136)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5@5.1/org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5@5.1/org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5@5.1/org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:165)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5@5.1/org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5@5.1/org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
    at org.apache.httpcomponents.client5.httpclient5@5.1/org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96)
( this goes on... )

There doesn't appear to be anything amiss on the server, it just stops seeing new connections (it's built on top of Undertow if that's relavent)
What's interesting is that if I restart the test immediately then it fails almost straight away with this error.  If I wait a few minutes then it'll run for about a minute again, and manages somewhere close to 10k requests before it falls over.  This makes me think it's running out of some OS-level resource which takes a while to be replenished?  Like handles or something?
Anyone got any ideas?
EDIT: It's worth mentioning that if I kill the server process and restart it quickly then I still see this issue, which leads me to believe it's not some kind of error accumulating in the server side code.

A few things I would look. The server receiving the requests, how is its configuration for max number of allowed connections. Does it have persistence sessions enabled (this would generate files which then is dependent on the OS max file descriptors, assuming *nix system), Whats the timeout set for the connections on the server, check if your machine has some kind of firewall blocking excessive number of connections. Also check redhat docs for undertown https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/performance_tuning_guide/undertow_tuning

maybe do the test using two different machines

Not required, but for a more realistic test, the client should be on a different machine and network from the server.

Your tests do not completely separate concerns.
Separate different concepts into different tests.

Test the client's request generation.  E.g. Make unit tests: Given particular sensor input (or whatever the input is in your scenario), expect particular JSON.

Test the server's response to selected correct requests, in a particular order.  (If possible, hard-code the requests.)  This is purely a correctness test, not a load test.

Test that the server can handle heavy load without generating "Connection refused".  You can send any request body here (such as a single hard-coded valid or invalid request).  You're not testing business logic (what the server does and returns), just the network and server infrastructure.


You can use an established load-testing tool for this, such as Apache JMeter or k6.
This will allow you to focus on your specific business logic, instead of writing a new load tester.
Again, hard-code the request bodies if possible.

Test that the server responds correctly under heavy load.  This is to verify that correctness of business logic does not degrade under load.


You make valid points, but I already have "correctness" tests implemented elsewhere, they make a relatively low rate of requests and validate that the system behaves correctly.  What i'm trying to investigate here is simply how the code performs when flooded.  Where are the limits? What's my performance statement etc.

#3 in my answer addresses that ("how the code performs when flooded").  Your current question is posed as a problem implementing the client load tester ("Problems using Apache httpclient lib"), but with discussion of the server mixed in.  #3 recommends you use an established, documented, configurable tool.  That will answer your questions ("Where are the limits? [...]").  You'll know it's not a problem with your custom client.  Once you've identified the server's limits, you can ask a question about the server (not about your client) on either Server Fault or Stack Overflow.
